# (android textwatcher)how to push a textWatcher on firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, textwatcher

I am doing a chat app and got stocked on how to make textWatcher which will push on the firebase data structure under user-typing
. I want to push a data structure wherein on the data structure you will see if the user is typing. when the user is typing the data structure under user-typing is true. if the user is not typing then it will become false. i tried this code but it seems wrong because every time i run the program. When I click the ediText. it will automatically make a data structure key for a user

```
final Firebase test = firebase.child("room-typing").push();
    test.setValue("true");
    final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            if (s == editText) {
                firebase.child("room-typing").child(test.getKey()).child("test").setValue("true");
            } else {
                firebase.child("room-typing").child(test.getKey()).child("test").setValue("false");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can i ask you Something? I tried a different method. I make a boolean value when typing to set as true . and after typing over at the enter button click i changed the same value to false. will it work for you?

Comment: yes , thats my point ,

Comment: Were r u getting the error?

Comment: on the firebase it self , when pushing the textWatcher , firebase automatically create a data structure everytime i click the editText ,,

Comment: my purpose is when i send a  message on firebase , automatically it will create a data structure of users and roomtyping , under room typing you will see all users who are typing , there i got stocked ,users contains name,timeStamp and message is working but on room typing it's not working ,

Comment: i think it's not running because it's not boolean formatted? urgh idk

Comment: As you are creating a push value this is happening

Comment: final Firebase test = firebase.child("room-typing").push();  remove the . push and try. Check is that what you need

Comment: yup what happens is when i clicked the editText and start typing , firebase automatically created a key ,which is not , it must appear when i send a message , so that it will register on the users key. got it?

Comment: i dont get your logic. anyway .push() will generate a unique key by firebase. if u dosent need that key . u must just delet that .push()

Comment: yes , i did  remove the push , and now when i type on the EditText, firebase  create a key "test" and it's value is false , which is correct , but when i start typing it doesn't turn into true , how was that?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating that new key yourself, by calling `push()`. From the [documentation for `push()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_push):

> Generates a new child location using a unique key and returns a Firebase reference to it.

I added some comments to you code, to mark where things happen:

```
// This next line creates a new key
final Firebase test = firebase.child("room-typing").push();

test.setValue("true");
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int count, int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                              int before, int count) {
        if (s == editText) {
            // This next line uses the new key you created above
            firebase.child("room-typing").child(test.getKey()).child("Onediver").setValue("true");
        } else {
            // As does the next line here
            firebase.child("room-typing").child(test.getKey()).child("Onediver").setValue("false");
        }
    }
});
```

To prevent the creation of a new child, you should **not** call push, but depend on a known child, such as:

```
final Firebase test = firebase.child("room-typing").child("jaymee");
```

Comment: yes , i did  remove the push , and now when i type on the EditText, firebase  create a key "test" and it's value is false , which is correct , but when i start typing it doesn't turn into true , how was that?

Comment: s == editText ? s is a CharSequence and editText is EditText. this will always be False and it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do this. **An easy way and there is an elegant way**.

For elegant way look into: *http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html*

#### Here's the easy way:

Create somewhere a custom countdown timer:

```
public class MyCountDownTimmer extends CountDownTimer {

public MyCountDownTimmer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
  super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}

@Override public void onTick(long l) {

}

@Override public void onFinish() {
  databaseReference.child("room-typing").child(room_name).child(user_id_or_name).setValue("false");
  isTyping = false;
}
}
```

**Declare your countdown timer**

```
private MyCountDownTimmer isTypingTimmer = new MyCountDownTimmer(1000, 1000);
private boolean isTyping = false;


editText_message.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    isTypingTimmer.cancel();
    isTypingTimmer.start();
    if (!isTyping) {
      databaseReference.child("room-typing").child(room_name).child(user_id_or_name).setValue("true");
      isTyping = true;
    }
  }
});
```